# How to effect options of ' TMenubutton' by ttk.Style?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

This is my code

```
    s.Opstyle = ttk.Style()
   
    s.Opstyle.configure('my.TMenubutton', font=('Microsoft Yahei', 9))
    '''Farme2 function area'''
    s.TransChoose = ttk.OptionMenu(s.fm2, s.v , '',
                        *list_zh
                        ,command=s.setlang,style='my.TMenubutton')
    #name = s.TransChoose.winfo_class()
```

I found that writing this only works on the currently selected option, but has no effect on the text (as *list_zh in code) in the list that appears when I click it.
selected option:

[image: selected option]

others options

[image: others options]

Comment: You need to configure it explicitly: `s.TransChoose['menu'].configure(font=('Microsoft Yahei', 9))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. There is another question.How can I know the structure of this control?